# How to prevent attack on realtime database in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ddos

I have already implemented Firebase App Check and Enforced firebase realtime database. Still I am under attack and I have a lot of bill to pay so at last I needed to delete my Firebase Project. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *firebaser here* If you're seeing a malicious attack on your database, [file a high-priority incident with Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Always ensure you are using the correct Security Rules to validate your firebase project and only allow the expected data to be uploaded. This is covered in the Security Rules documentation provided [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

If it is malicious abuse, you can contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) immediately